# Unity3d - Audio rough sound when transition between play and pause

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity script that will play audio (foot step) while the player is moving. The script is working, but there is one more problem, the audio seems too rough (and maybe can harm my speaker hehe) when transition between play and pause.

This is my script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
    Rigidbody playerRigid;
    private Vector3 pindah;
    public AudioSource audioSource;
    public AudioClip audioClip;
    public float lowPitchRange = .95f;
    public float hiPitchRange = 1.05f;

    void Awake () {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
        audioSource.clip = audioClip;
        float randomPitch = Random.Range (lowPitchRange, hiPitchRange);
        audioSource.pitch = randomPitch;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        //mengambil komponen rigidbody player
        playerRigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        //untuk mendapatkan input dari virtual joystick button
        float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
        float v = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");

        if ((h != 0f || v != 0f) && !audioSource.isPlaying) {
            audioSource.Play ();
        } else {
            audioSource.Pause ();
        }
        //memindah posisi player sesuai input yang didapat
        pindah = new Vector3 (h, 0.0f, v);
        playerRigid.velocity = pindah;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to change the code like this:

```
if (h != 0f || v != 0f) {
     if (!audioSource.isPlaying) audioSource.Play ();
} else {
     audioSource.Pause ();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is the audio source pops when you pause it, maybe you should consider to fade the volume instead with something similar to this (I haven't tested myself, I will try it later):

```
// fade/increase time in seconds
public float rateTime = 1; 

public FadeSound() { 
    //audioSource.Play ();
    StartCoroutine(_FadeSound); 
    }

public IncreaseSound() { 
    StartCoroutine(_IncreaseSound); 
}

IEnumerator _FadeSound() {
    float t = rateTime;

    while (t > 0) {
        yield return null;
        t-= Time.deltaTime;
        source.volume = t/rateTime;
    }
    yield break;
    //yield audioSource.Pause ();
}

IEnumerator _IncreaseSound() {
    float t = 0;

    while (t < 1) {
        yield return null;
        t+= Time.deltaTime;
        source.volume = t/rateTime;
    }
    yield break;
}

if ((h != 0f || v != 0f) && !audioSource.isPlaying) {
    IncreaseSound();
} else {
    FadeSound();
}
```

Comment: Usually it's a good idea to start this kind of smooth transition from the current value of the edited parameter i.e. source.volume in this case. Otherwise you'll get pops if you toggle too quickly between FadeSound and IncreaseSound as the volume jumps instantaneously to the start value of the transition which is 0 or 1. You might also need to stop any conflicting coroutines before starting a new one.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback matti, I will update the answer this afternoon. I feel this is not what the user was expecting, but it will be useful for me anyway. Thanks!!